# how to get single value of group by statement with only_full_group_by enabled in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying to get any one customer associated with a company like this:

```
select company_id, id from `customer` 
where company_id IS NOT NULL 
group by `company_id`
```

I get the error:

> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column customer.id which is not functionally dependent
>   on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

How can I accmplish this without disabling `only_full_group_by` ?

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY is meant to be used with aggregate functions. Use LIMIT to get one row.

```
select company_id, id from `customer` 
where company_id IS NOT NULL 
limit 1
```

EDIT: (after question clarification):

If you want each unique combination of company_id and customer_id, use DISTINCT:

```
select distinct company_id, id 
from `customer` 
where company_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This only returns one row.  I want to return 1 row for the one to many relationship between customer and company.

Comment: In that case use DISCTINCT optimization. The distinct shows each similar row only once.